# Access hosted MongoDB through Rest

Tags: mongodb, rest, digital-ocean

Let me preface this by saying that at this point I'm an absolute beginner in this area.

So I'm trying to access my MongoDB server hosted on DigitalOcean by using Rest to transfer data from the database to a user's webpage. (Something like [what mongolab has](https://mongolab.com/).)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

## You don't connect via REST

The way you connect to a mongo server is with this syntax

`mongodb://<username>:<password>@<hostname or ip>:<listening port>/<db name>`

Once your connected to the server, you can do whatever you want to and run any commands to the db.

```js
//
// Simple Node.js connection example
//

var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var uri = "mongodb://myuser:mypass@ds028017.mongolab.com:28017/mydb";

mnogo.connection(uri, function(err,db) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error: unable to connect to database");
        return;
    }

    // your code here

});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTTP basic auth. `mongodb://` is not `http://`, and the `user:password` notation has nothing to do with HTTP in itself. HTTP Basic auth will use the combined string, base64-encode it and put in an HTTP Authorization header, none of which makes sense in the context of a proprietary, binary connection.